# Python "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple"

Tags: python, lambda

I wrote a piece python code like this

```
import random

val_hist = []
for i in range(100):
    val_hist.append(random.randint(0,1000))


def print__(x):
    print type(x[1])
map(lambda x: print__(x), list(enumerate(val_hist)))

l_tmp = list(enumerate(val_hist))
idx_list = map(lambda x: x[0], l_tmp)
val_list = map(lambda x: x[1], l_tmp)

print idx_list
print val_list

reduce(lambda sum, x: sum + x[1], list(enumerate(val_hist)))
print reduce(lambda sum, x: sum + x, val_hist)
print reduce(lambda sum, x: sum + x[1], list(enumerate(val_hist)))
```

When I ran this code, I got this error "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple".
Does anyone know how this happened?
Or does anyone know how python function reduce works exactly?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a third argument to reduce, which is the `initializer`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

> If initializer is not given and iterable contains only one item, the
>   first item is returned.

Since you aren't explicitly providing an `initializer` parameter, `reduce` is using the first element from `list(enumerate(val_hist))`, which happens to be a tuple. You're trying to add this tuple together with `x[1]` which is an integer.

So, simply update your `reduce` with an `initializer` value of 0, like so:

```
>>> reduce(lambda sum, x: sum + x[1], list(enumerate(val_hist)), 0)
>>> 48279
```

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thank you very much.